# Issue with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use promises. Basically puting http connections in one js and calling from another js. But I am not able to do so. What's the mistake here?

http.js

```
'use strict';
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports.get = async (url) => {
  console.log("inside get method");
  const promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    console.log("inside promise");
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => {
        console.log("inside fetch");
        resolve(res.json());
      })
      .catch(json => reject(Error(json)));
  })
  return promise;
}
```

main.js

```
'use strict';
const http = require('/opt/http.js')

module.exports.httpTest = async (event) => {
  let url = 'http://www.someurl.com/';
  console.log("calling get method");
  http.get(url).then(
  function (data) {
  console.log("inside http then")
  console.log(data);
}).catch(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
console.log("exited get method");
}
```

As you can see in http.js I have written a wrapper for GET request which I am trying to use in main.js.

When I execute main.js, nothing fails, but not get displayed on console. What I am doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

I have added console logs everywhere... and when I call httpTest from anywhere, here is what I am getting

```
calling get method
inside get method
inside promise
exited get method
```

basically it's not going inside fetch

Comment: 'when I execute main.js' - this, probably, I'm guessing you aren't invoking the code properly. There are some issues with your code in general, but nothing that would prevent you from seeing _something_ in the logs when ran.

Comment: fetch returns a promise.... It makes no sense to resolve and reject like you are doing.

Comment: I don’t understand why you don’t just write `module.exports.get = async (url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()).catch((err) => new Error(err));` or something similar.

Comment: Did you forget to call `httpTest()`? (you also aren't using `event`)

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Besides the other two issues (you're uselessly wrapping fetch, and not calling httpTest anywhere), are you intending to import from `/opt`?

Comment: I am calling httpTest from somewhere elsse... so I am calling it

Comment: main idea is to have a http with all the methods in there like GET, POST... and use wrappers that return promise. Based on status code, I will generate some standardised messages... so I need this pattern

Comment: If you use a full-featured library such as `got()` for your http requests, there is no need for the kind of wrapper you're doing.  It has everything built-in.  It's all promise-based and it will read/parse your JSON in one call without the extra chained promise that `fetch()` uses.

Comment: I need to write some generic code inside these methods which I haven't put yet... This is the basic I am working on... And most of them only supports https and not http.. I am inside VPC and there is not https... so i need to use something very basic

Comment: Instead of reject(Error(json)) in catch block use reject(json). Looks fetch ends in error due to the additional wrapping in catch you are not getting the log printed.

Answer (score -1):

Don’t create a useless extra promise.

```
  // this is a code smell
  const promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    console.log("inside promise");
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => {
        console.log("inside fetch");
        resolve(res.json());
      })
      .catch(json => reject(Error(json)));
  })
  return promise;
```

Just `return fetch(url);` which already returns a promise. Your wrapper promise adds nothing.

Second, your `exited get method` is going to run outside the promise chain. If you want that to run after get finishes you need to await the http.get call inside HttpTest.